# NHibernate and Oracle Lite

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

Has anyone able to successfully used NHibernate with Oracle Lite,If yes can you tell me what do we need to mention in hibernate.cfg.xml , I mean which dialect and how do we connect to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of NH you are using? It seems that this feature is quite new only implemented within the actual Aplha: 2.1.0.Alpha1.
Improvements:
* [NH-1644] - Oracle Lite Driver With Working Query Parameters

I haven't tried so i can not say what connection string to use but the dialect should be 'OracleLiteDialect' as the Alexandre Payment says [here](http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-1596). The Jira [issues](http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-1644) are solved so it should be worth a try.

Please post the connection string if you were able to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the app.config for a test project I made some time ago :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate"/>
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.OracleLiteDialect</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OdbcDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">dsn=TheDSN;uid=TheUserId;pwd=ThePassword</property>
      <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
</configuration>
```

Note : to connect to the local Oracle Lite database :

- the DSN is usually built as `<Oracle lite user name>_<Database name>`
- the user id is `SYSTEM`
- the password is the actual password of the Oracle Lite user

For instance, if your OL user name is SCOTT, your password is TIGER, and the database name is FOO, the Oracle Lite connection string is : `dsn=SCOTT_FOO;uid=SYSTEM;pwd=TIGER`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The namespaces for Driver and Dialect classes are `NHibernate.Driver` and `NHibernate.Dialect` respectively. You can use Intellisense or Reflector to see exactly what is available.

A Session Factory configuration for Oracle Lite:

```
<property name="connection.connection_string">...</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleLiteDataClientDriver</property>
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.OracleLiteDialect</property>
```

Oracle connection strings are described [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle).